# Syntax error in SQL request "... OVER ... ORDER BY... BETWEEN..." (older versus new version)

Tags: sql, mariadb, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a moving average that would average the value of the row with the previous 9 values from column "values" of my SQL table.

Basically, I have something like this:

```
dateEvent                values
2021-07-05 06:00:10       2.0
2021-07-05 14:00:10       3.0
2021-07-05 20:00:10       4.0
2021-07-06 06:00:10       3.0
2021-07-06 14:00:10       1.0
2021-07-06 20:00:10       5.0
2021-07-07 06:00:10       4.0
2021-07-07 14:00:10       2.0
2021-07-07 20:00:10       3.0
2021-07-08 06:00:10       3.0
2021-07-08 14:00:10       3.0
2021-07-08 20:00:10       6.0
2021-07-09 06:00:10       3.0
2021-07-09 14:00:10       3.0
2021-07-09 20:00:10       5.0
2021-07-10 06:00:10       2.0
2021-07-10 14:00:10       3.0
2021-07-10 20:00:10       1.0
```

and I would like:

```
dateEvent                values      averageValues    averagePerDay
2021-07-05 06:00:10       2.0           2.0
2021-07-05 14:00:10       3.0           2.5                2.50
2021-07-05 20:00:10       4.0           3.0
2021-07-06 06:00:10       3.0           3.0
2021-07-06 14:00:10       8.0           4.0                3.60
2021-07-06 20:00:10       4.0           4.0
2021-07-07 06:00:10       2.0           3.7
2021-07-07 14:00:10       2.0           3.5                3.54
2021-07-07 20:00:10       3.0           3.44
2021-07-08 06:00:10       3.0           3.4
2021-07-08 14:00:10       3.0           3.5                3.57
2021-07-08 20:00:10       6.0           3.8
2021-07-09 06:00:10       3.0           3.7
2021-07-09 14:00:10       3.0           3.7                3.60
2021-07-09 20:00:10       5.0           3.4
2021-07-10 06:00:10       2.0           3.2
2021-07-10 14:00:10       3.0           3.3                3.23
2021-07-10 20:00:10       1.0           3.2
```

I had no problem on my local server (last version) using:

```
SELECT *,
    (CASE WHEN COUNT(*)
    OVER(ORDER BY dateEvent ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) > 10
        THEN AVG(values)
        OVER(ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING)
        ELSE values
        END)
        AS 'averageValues' FROM f16
        group by CAST(dateEvent AS DATE)
```

However, on my older server (I don't have the permission to update it), it's giving me a syntax error on line 3 around the "OVER(ORDER BY...".

Any ideas what's wrong? I tried different other ways but none of them worked. I'm open to other ways but I think I'm close. Just a small syntax problem.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @laurent, which database are you using? Can you put the tag on your question, pls?

Comment: Sorry, the version where it doesn't work is 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2 - Debian 9.13

Comment: Window functions were first introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server/

Comment: Thanks. Good to know! Would you have any recommandations which other way I could try that?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  You're right Gordon, I updated my question. Hope it's easier to understand now

Comment: You should upgrade. [MariaDB 10.1 passed its end of life in October 2020](https://endoflife.date/mariadb). Continuing to use software that may have security vulnerabilities that won't be fixed is a hazard.

Comment: @BillKarwin  I know Bill but unfortunately, I'm not in control of this database. I hope the admin will update it asap. By the time, I need to find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to average the last 10 values from column "values" of my SQL table.

You can do this using a subquery:

```
select avg(value)
from (select f16.*
      from f16
      order by dateEvent desc
      limit 10
     ) f;
```

Window functions are not needed for the problem that you are describing.

EDIT:

Based on your comment:

```
select f16.*,
       avg(value) over (order by dateevent rows between 10 preceding and current row) as avg_10
from f16;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=4eb3a5ee75f137ec198a60c414a7dc76) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you ... and really sorry for the misunderstanding. I actually re-edited my question. I meant to make a moving average that would average the current row with the 9 preceding rows. Not just the last 10. Sorry again

Comment: I tried but it says an alias was previously found near avg_10!

Comment: @Laurent . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The code does not generate a syntax error.

Comment: It does work indeed on my local server, but not on the other server. I will contact the admin to update it. Thanks a lot for your help.